# SSIS - Importing data into tables

Tags: ssis

When i am importing data into tables it is failing with the following error

"The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure."

I have the structures of the table like below

INSERT INTO [dbo].[BlockedPID]
([BlockedPIDID],[GroupChannelID],[RequestID],[SerialStart],[SerialEnd],[ReasonBlockedID],ChangeControl],[LastModifiedDate],[LastModifiedBy],[MessageID],[TenantID],[EventID]
,[DetailUUID])

VALUES(,,,
,,,,
,,,,,)

USE [KISDB]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[RetailRuleException]
([RetailRuleExceptionID],[RequestID],[RetailRuleMasterID],[MPCMasterID],[GroupChannelIDFrom]
,[GroupChannelIDTo],[SerialStart],[SerialEnd],[RIT],[ROT],[RAT],[ActivationLimit],[ActivationOverrideLimit],[IsActive],[ChangeControl],[LastModifiedDate],[LastModifiedBy])

VALUES(,,,
,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,)
GO

We have 'ChangeControl' column with binary(8) datatype. and DFT is not able to store it in memory while importing thr data.

Could any one help me out to mitigate this problem?

Thanks,
Vijay Sharma

Comment: I believe your issue may lie in the way you are using the destination component. Instead of using the above statements, which I assume are in two separate destinations, if you change the destination source to a table with the fast load option, select `dbo.BlockedPID` in one OLE Destination and `dbo.RetailRuleException` in the other and map your columns appropriately, does the error go away?